# Device menu does not show up on my Virtual Windows10

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I have Ubuntu 16.04(host) and Windows10(guest) on my OracleVM.I want to install guest addition but where is Device tab?
[image]

These are my UserInterface settings now
[image]

This is my menubar
[image]

EDIT

FINALLY SOLVED,Just actived here Device button.

Comment: What device tab? https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html Quoting: *In the "Devices" **menu** in the **virtual machine's menu bar**, VirtualBox has a handy menu item named "Insert Guest Additions CD image", which mounts the Guest Additions ISO file inside your virtual machine. A Windows guest should then automatically start the Guest Additions installer, which installs the Guest Additions into your Windows guest. *

Comment: @MichaelBay Yes,but I can not find it in Virtualbox manager either.Where is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Virtual Box >= 5.2 we can fine tune the appearance of a virtual machine. This includes hiding and showing the top bar where the devices menu resides.

To enable the user interface settings right click anywhere in the machine's settings to show the drop down menu where we can tick to show the user interface settings:

[image]

Then we can change the appearance on the newly available user interface dialog. Click on any item from <kbd>File</kbd>, <kbd>Machine</kbd>,...,<kbd>Help</kbd> to enable or disable the corresponding entry or click on the dropdown menu there to customise entries. Tick next to the mini tool bar to enable it as a whole:

[image]

---

**Note on the menu bar.** We may have accidentally removed it with an option appearing on right click on that menu bar. It then will be gone and can not be clicked again until we restore it as shown above.

[image]

From the *Settings...* menu entry we can control the entries displayed in a same way as from the user interface settings above.